# How to create a pie subplots that takes multiple inputs

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, pie-chart

I want to build two pie subplots that takes as input the country, the sector and the year. And I want to see the proportions of job positions that mens have, and the proportions of job positions that women have.

(for example for man 'CEo'=23%, President=20%, Member=57%).

And in the same way the pie for womens

Comment: can you also include the `app.layout` from your code? this will make it easier for people to reproduce your dash app, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems in your callback function. Since you want headcount, after you filter by country, year, and settore, you should filter only rows where the field `_UNIT = NR` because these represent absolute numbers of men and women in these positions, then groupby gender and position (we don't need to include country, year, or settore in the groupby because these are already accounted for in the selection), and then sum the values column.

```
@app.callback(Output('pie', 'figure'),
            [Input('year-slider', 'value'),
            Input('country-selection', 'value'),
            Input('settore-selection', 'value')])
def update_graph(year_slider, country_selection, settore_selection):

    ## to avoid modifying the original data
    m3 = df.copy()

    if country_selection != 'Select all':
        m3 = m3[m3['geo']==country_selection]

    m3 = m3[m3['time'] == year_slider]

    if settore_selection is not None and settore_selection in m3['NACE'].unique():
        m3 = m3[m3['NACE']==settore_selection]

    ## you want the headcount of people so use _UNIT == 'NR'
    m3_grouped = m3[m3['_UNIT'] == 'NR'].groupby(['POSITION','sex'])['value'].sum().reset_index(name='count')
    m3_grouped_men = m3_grouped[m3_grouped['sex'] == 'Men']
    m3_grouped_women = m3_grouped[m3_grouped['sex'] == 'Women']

    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'pie'}, {'type':'pie'}]])
    
    
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie( values=m3_grouped['count'],labels=m3_grouped_men['POSITION'],
                            domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5]), name='Men'),
                1, 1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie( values=m3_grouped_women['count'],labels=m3_grouped_women['POSITION'],
                            
                            domain=dict(x=[0.5, 1.0]), name='Women'),
                1, 2)
        
    
    # Use `hole` to create a donut-like pie chart
    
    fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name")
    
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="How the positions are distributed in men and women?",
        # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
        annotations=[dict(text='Men', x=0.18, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False),
                        dict(text='Women', x=0.82, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False)])    
        
    return fig
```

Here is the full code and dash app:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash import Input, Output, html, dcc


app=dash.Dash(__name__, meta_tags=[{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width"}],
             external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
df=pd.read_csv('report.csv')
#fill NAs with zeros
df=df.fillna(0)

#Create the list to show in dropdown element from a specific dataset column
country = df['geo'].unique()
country = country.tolist()
country.insert(0, 'Select all')
settore = df['NACE'].unique()

app.layout=html.Div([
    
    
    
    html.Div([
        html.H1(children='A gender analysis ',
                style={'textAlign':'center'}),
        html.P(children='A case study of the top company from 2011 al 2023',
              style={'textAlign':'left', 'margin-left':'1%'})
    
    ], style={"margin-bottom": "3vw", 'margin-left':'1%', "border":"2px purple solid", 'background-color':'#FF69B4'}),
    
    
    html.Div([
        "Select the year:",
        dcc.Slider(id='year-slider',
                   included=False,
                   updatemode='drag',
                   tooltip={'always_visible':True},
                   min=2011,
                   max=2023,
                   step=1,
                   dots=True,
                   value=2016,
                   marks={str(tm):str(tm) for tm in range(2011, 2023)},
                   className='dcc_compon'),
     
    ], style={"margin-bottom": "3vw", 'margin-left':'1%', "border":"2px purple solid", 'background-color':'lightblue'}), 
    
    
    html.Div([
        
        
        html.Div([
             #dropdown country
            html.Div([
                html.H4('Select the country:', className='fix_label',style={'color':'black'}),
                dcc.Dropdown(id='country-selection',
                             multi=False,
                             clearable=True,
                             disabled=False,
                             style={'display':True, 'width':'330px', 'padding':'5px', 'color':'black', 'margin-bottom':'0.5vw'},
                             value='Select all',
                             placeholder='Select  country',
                             options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in country],
                             className='dcc_compon'),
            ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top', 'margin-left': '0.5vw', 'margin-top': '3vw'}),
                
            html.Br(),
            
            
            
            
            html.Div(id='country-output',
                    style={'margin-left':'0.5vw'}),
            
            html.Br(),
            
            
           
            #dropdown settore
            html.Div([
                html.H4('Which is the sector of interest?', className= 'fix_label', style={'color':'black'}),
                dcc.Dropdown(id='settore-selection',
                             multi=False,
                             clearable=True,
                             disabled=False,
                             style={'display':True, 'width':'330px', 'padding':'5px', 'color':'black', 'margin-bottom':'0.5vw'},
                             placeholder='Select sector',
                             value='All sectors',
                             options=[{'label': z, 'value': z} for z in settore], className='dcc_compon'),
                ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top', 'margin-left': '0.5vw', 'margin-top': '3vw'}),
                
            html.Br(),
            
            
            
            html.Div(id='settore-output',
                    style={'margin-left':'0.5vw'}),
            
            html.Br(),
            
       
            
        ], style={'background-color':'#FFF0F5','width': '30%', 'display':'inline-block', 'float':'left',"margin-bottom": "10px", 'margin-left':'1%', "border":"2px purple solid"}),
        
        
        
        
        html.Div([
            
            
            
            
            dcc.Graph(id='pie',
                      config={'displayModeBar':'hover'},
                      style={'width':'90%','display':'inline-block','float':'left','margin-left':'0.5%', 'margin-bottom':'1%'}),
            
            
            
            
        ], style={'width': '68%', 'display':'inline-block','float':'right',"margin-bottom": "10px", 'margin-left':'1%', "border":"2px purple solid"}),
        
            
            
        
    ])
    
], id="mainContainer", style={"display":"flex", "flex-direction":"column"})

@app.callback(Output('pie', 'figure'),
            [Input('year-slider', 'value'),
            Input('country-selection', 'value'),
            Input('settore-selection', 'value')])
def update_graph(year_slider, country_selection, settore_selection):

    ## to avoid modifying the original data
    m3 = df.copy()

    if country_selection != 'Select all':
        m3 = m3[m3['geo']==country_selection]

    m3 = m3[m3['time'] == year_slider]

    if settore_selection is not None and settore_selection in m3['NACE'].unique():
        m3 = m3[m3['NACE']==settore_selection]

    ## you want the headcount of people so use _UNIT == 'NR'
    m3_grouped = m3[m3['_UNIT'] == 'NR'].groupby(['POSITION','sex'])['value'].sum().reset_index(name='count')
    m3_grouped_men = m3_grouped[m3_grouped['sex'] == 'Men']
    m3_grouped_women = m3_grouped[m3_grouped['sex'] == 'Women']

    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'pie'}, {'type':'pie'}]])
    
    
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie( values=m3_grouped['count'],labels=m3_grouped_men['POSITION'],
                            domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5]), name='Men'),
                1, 1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie( values=m3_grouped_women['count'],labels=m3_grouped_women['POSITION'],
                            
                            domain=dict(x=[0.5, 1.0]), name='Women'),
                1, 2)
        
    
    # Use `hole` to create a donut-like pie chart
    
    fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name")
    
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="How the positions are distributed in men and women?",
        # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
        annotations=[dict(text='Men', x=0.18, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False),
                        dict(text='Women', x=0.82, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False)])    
        
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=4000)
```

[image]

Comment: @user22300466 it looks like you're not including `sex` in the groupby, and you're passing the same data to both pie charts. i've rewritten your callback function and have updated my answer using sample data

Comment: If you have a link to the actual data set you’re using, I’d be happy to take a look

Comment: @user22300466 I've updated my answer – i'm modifying the groupby in your callback function to sum up the values column instead of using `count`